# connecting to external device though bluetooth in iOS5

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, hardware

I found many question about bluetooth but I don't know if there are up to date.
With iOS 5 it is possible to connect the iphone to another device for sending and receiving data?
There is an external device SDK but I don't understand if is necessary the authentication chip (made for iphone) for third party hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Bluetooth Device Access Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Intro/BT_Intro.html) in Apple's developer center, it should answer all of your questions.

Comment: I just give a quick read but it seems related to OS X that doesn't have the limit imposed by Apple on iOS... I just need to know if it's necessary an authentication chip on third party hardware ;)